# Does the Acer Ferrari One support hardware assisted virtualization?

Tags: virtualization, vt-x

Does anyone know if the [Acer Ferrari One](http://www.acer.co.uk/ferrarione/specifications.html) supports hardware assisted virtualization (it should easy to find out by running [Microsoft's Hardware-Assisted Virtualization Detection Tool](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163321) on that machine).

There is lot's of speculation around the web, but I haven't found a definitive answer yet (and would like to confirm that this feature will be working before buying one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got confirmation in a German-speaking [forum](http://www.planet3dnow.de/vbulletin/showpost.php?s=4bf57f66eaa4a7201be111294576ff0f&p=4076529&postcount=83) that hardware-assisted virtualization is indeed supported.

Answer (score -1):

No.  Acer customer support confirmed to me today that the virtualization is turned off, and it is not possible to turn it on.